# Category & product url SEO

Tags: seo, e-commerce

What is considered to be best practice for url structuring these days?

for some reason i thought including an extension at the end of a url was once you got down to the 'lowest' part of your hierarchy e.g.

/category/sub-category/product.html

then all category urls would be:

/category/sub-category/

rather than including an extension at the end because there is still further to go down the structure.

looking forward to your thoughts.
Andy.

#### EDIT

Just for clarification purposes: I'm looking at this from an ecommerce perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but I'll reply as I understand it.
As to use or not to use file extensions, according to Google's representative Matt Cutts, Google crawls .html, .php, or .asp, but you should keep away from .exe, .dll,.bin. They signify largely binary data, so may be ignored by Googlebot.

Still, when designing SEO friendly URLs, keep in mind they should be short and descriptive, so you may use your keywords to rank higher. So, if you have good keywords in your category names, why not let them be visible in the URL.

Make sure you're using static instead of dynamic URLs, they are easier to remember, and they don't change.

Comment: Hi Christina, thanks for your response. Based on what i've read online there is no 'best practice' way to display urls except to use keywords and get rid of query strings. It all comes down to preference. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/webmasters/kfAFrv-O9Ws/-IVbMiqSCRwJ and my question was asking from an ecommerce perspective whats best practice for referencing category urls as apposed to product urls

Comment: Ok, now I see what you mean! It would be best to edit your question to emphasise what exatly you're asking.